# How to sort by date in Mongolab REST API?

Tags: mlab

My query url is:

```
var url = 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/database/collections/collection?'
            + 'q={'
            + '\"visible\": true'
            + ', \"date\": ' + JSON.stringify( jsonDate )
            + ', \"country\": \"' + country + "\""
            + '}'
            + '&s={"date": -1}'
            + '&apiKey=' + this.key;
```

I have and option to sort after with Backbone or Jquery, but I hope to do it with query.

Comment: It looks like you already have the `s` (sort value) specified in your url as `{"date": -1}` (or date, descending). What aspect of the query isn't working? I also don't think you should have to use backslash to escape values which are already in single quotes.

Comment: I know, but sorting hasn't applied. So that's the reason of the question.

Comment: So the query returns the expected results, but unsorted? Have you contacted MongoLab since this is their API?

Comment: Well, I don't. But I think it's my only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query is working. Problem was in PhoneGap framework, because I've open platform related JS/HTML code and made changes in there. But changes should be made in special www directory, one with source for every platforms.

Answer (score 1):

The url you generated is correct, however it is not a valid URL unless you do proper URL encoding of special characters like spaces.
Use `encodeURIcomponent` of your query parameters, and it should work.

Or use jQuery to pass your parameter as javascript object in jQuery.get method.

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer using cursor.sort(sort).

```
cursor.sort(date)
```

check this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/